# Laravel 9 project, Vite manifest not found on server

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-9

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel 9 project on an Ubuntu 20 server.

On localhost everything works, but on the server, when I try to open the website, I get this error:

```
Vite manifest not found at: /var/www/example.com/public/resources/assets/js/myScripts.js/manifest.json
```

The line in the Blade template producing the error seems to be this one:

```
@vite('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'resources/assets/js/myScripts.js')
```

I made sure to run `npm run build` and checked that the `manifest.json` file is generated correctly, which it is.

The content of `public/build/manifest.json` is something like this:

```
{
  "resources/assets/js/myScripts.js": {
    "file": "assets/myScripts.47ff47b1.js",
    "src": "resources/assets/js/myScripts.js",
    "isEntry": true,
    "imports": [
      "_jquery.0178a139.js"
    ]
  },
  ...
  ...
  "resources/assets/sass/app.scss": {
    "file": "assets/app.439d8351.css",
    "src": "resources/assets/sass/app.scss",
    "isEntry": true
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the resources as an array in your statement, when passing more than one file:

```
@vite(['resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'resources/assets/js/myScripts.js'])
```

The second parameter in `@vite` looks like its for setting a custom path for the `manifest.json` file, which in this case is looking at your `myScripts.js`

Comment: thanks, this solved it. I would have never noticed it, also because on local host, using the `dev` environment it doesn't produce the same error